# How to get get data as IQueryable from Sql Server ODBC Connection

Tags: sql-server, odbc, odata

I am trying to implement OData over odbc connection layer, I am currently not able to get data as IQueryable from ODBC driver (ODBC connection is for Sql Server)

Is there any driver that can return data as IQueryable through ODBC Connection?

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of IQueryables that they don't actually execute on the database. IQueryables are just in-memory representations of a query that one can execute on demand to get results. It's a flavor of a lazy loaded list.

Given this I don't think that you are necessarily asking the right question. Does that make sense?